# jquery tokeninput : how to pass a dynamic array for autocompletion

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-tokeninput

With tokenInput, my autocompletion returns nothing and I don't find why.

First I do a query on the database to find all the contacts for the connected user.

I get an array like for instance :

```
$contacts = Array( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => John ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => Peter ) )
```

Then I use http_build_query as I want to pass the array through URL :

```
$contacts_url =http_build_query($contacts);
```

which returns :

```
print_r($contacts_url)= 0%5Bid%5D=1&0%5Bname%5D=John&1%5Bid%5D=3&1%5Bname%5D=Peter
```

Then I use tokenInputs, and I send my array through the url :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#my-text-input").tokenInput("<?php echo $this->webroot.'populate.php?'.$contacts_url ?>", {theme: "facebook"});
});
```

the populate.php page contains :

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/javascript');
    $a= $_GET;
    $json_string = json_encode($a);
    echo $json_string;
?>
```

If I open the php page ../populate.php?0%5Bid%5D=1&0%5Bname%5D=John&1%5Bid%5D=3&1%5Bname%5D=Peter i see:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"John"},{"id":"3","name":"Peter"}]
```

which I think looks good

But the autocompletion returns nothing :(

Any help much much appreciated !

Many thanks

Comment: Your search parameter is also sent as a get variable, which I imagine is messing up your json_encode. Have you tried using something like Chrome's web tools to see what response you get from the server on typing a character? If you can get a live demo up, that would be really helpful to see what's going on properly.

Comment: Also, is there a particular reason you're sending all your contacts from PHP, printing to Javascript, then sending back to the PHP again? It's an odd way of doing it! And if this is all you're doing, I don't see why you're requesting from a server at all, which not print to a local JSON array - jQuery TokenInput works with that too.

Comment: you are right twice! my url was messy, after passing through tokeninput() it changed the % into %25 and added &q=a at the end.  But your second comment is very valuable ! I removed this php file and did     $json_string = json_encode($contacts);
       
        <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#my-text-input").tokenInput(
           <?php 
            echo $json_string;
           ?>, 
           {theme: "facebook"}
          );
         });
        </script>

Comment: And now everything is working. Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the search parameter is also sent as a `$GET` variable, which I imagine would be messing up your JSON encode.

A much better way of doing this would be locally, as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#my-text-input").tokenInput("<?php echo json_encode($contacts) ?>", {theme: "facebook"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#searchword").tokenInput(            

    /* Given that $json_res = json_encode($user_arr); in the PHP. 
Using <?php echo $json_res ?> OR <?php echo json_encode($user_arr) ?> without quotes and blocks gives the same result. 

    The other way is to define var ar =<?php echo $json_res?>; in JS and pass it as .tokenInput(ar, {} */

               <?php echo $json_res ?>
            , {
                propertyToSearch: "username",
                theme: "facebook",
                preventDuplicates: true,
                excludeCurrent: true                    
            });
    });
```

// if JSON file has [{"id":"856","product":"sample1"}, {"id":"1035","product":"sample product 2"}], execute the following:

```
$('#product_tokens').tokenInput('/products.json', { propertyToSearch: 'product' });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.